# Method naming convention

Tags: coding-style, standards

If a method takes a class/struct as an input parameter, what is the best way to name it?

**Example**:

```
class Person{}
class Address{}

class Utility{
  //name **style 1** - use method overloading
  public void Save(Person p){}
  public void Save(Address a){}

  *//name **style 2** - use unique names that define what they are doing
  //or  public void SavePerson(Person p){}
  //and public void SaveAddress(Address a){}*
}
```

I personally like style 1 (Use the languages features - in this case overloading).
If you like style 1, can you point me to any "official" documentation, that states this to be a standard?

Comment: Go for Style 1 with method overloading

Comment: Matt - any object oriented language I guess.

Comment: I think both Oded and Fredrik Mork's comments are valid answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say your challenge is not in the field of method naming, but rather type design. A type that is responsible for saving *both* `Person` objects and `Address` objects seems like a type with [more than one responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Such a type will tend to grow and grow and grow and will eventually get hard to maintain. If you instead create more specialized types, method naming may automatically become a simpler task.

If you would still want to collect these methods in the same type, it's mostly a matter of style. One thing to perhaps think about is whether this type may be consumed by code written in another language, and that does not support method overloading. In such cases the longer names is the way to go. Otherwise just stick to what feels best (or whatever is the ruling convention at your workplace).

Comment: Fredrik, the scenario I am thinking of is when you have business entities that have no knowledge of how they are hydrated or persisted. Instead, the DAL is the one responsible for hydrating and persisting the entities (either from a webservice or a database or a local file-system). The DAL in this case would have the save methods.

Comment: Fredrik, another scenario that one class might end up with such methods is one that is incharge of Conversion between Business Entities and Data Transfer Objects (such as objects from web-service to business entities and vice-versa).

Comment: @Rajah: What I typically do in such scenarios is that I have repository classes for the different types of objects (such as `PersonRespository`, `AddressRepository`, ...). Such a repository can contain the necessary methods for fetching and storing the data for each type of object. This means (amongst other things) that the type responsible for one type of object remains unchanged if you need to change the storage code for another type; potentially more robust code along with smaller repository units.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of style.

If you don't like long method names, go with 1.

If you don't like long overload lists, go with 2.

The important bit is to keep consistent, so do not mix the two styles in one project.

If you are seeing that you have many such methods, you may need to rethink your design - perhaps a solution involving inheritance would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct names avoid entirely any problems associated with method overloading. For example:

- Ambiguity is avoided if an argument's type matches more than one of the candidates.
- In C++, overloaded methods can hide those of the same name in a superclass.
- In Java, type erasure prevents overloaded methods differing only by type parameterization.

It would also be worthwhile to ask whether polymorphism could be used instead of overloading.